# List of lists in racket

Tags: racket

I need to create this:

Define a min&max-lists function that consumes a list of lists
(where the type of the elements in the inner list may be any type).

The function returns a list of lists – such that for each inner list (in the
original list) the following is done –

1. If the list contains at least one number, then the list is replaced with a list of size two, containing the minimum and maximum in the list.
2. Otherwise, the list is replaced with a null.

**For example**

written in a form of a test that you can use:

```
(test (min&max-lists '((any "Benny" 10 OP 8) (any "Benny" OP (2 3))))
```

=> '((8 10) ()))
    (test (min&max-lists '((2 5 1 5 L) (4 5 6 7 3 2 1) ())) >> '((1 5) (1 7) ()))

For now, I have created a function that do it for one list.

How I do it for the list of lists??

**for example:**

```
(listhelp '(2 5 1 5 L)) 
-> : (Listof Number)>>'(1 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have `min&max` with the strange name `listhelp` you can use [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=map#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), use [`for/list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Flist#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29), or roll your own recursion:

```scm
(define (min&max-lists lol)
  (map min&max lol))

(define (min&max-lists lol)
  (for/list ([e (in-list lol)])
    (min&max e)))

(define (min&max-lists lol)
  (if (null? lol)
      '()
      (cons (min&max (car lol))
            (min&max-lists (cdr lol)))))
```